# php merge two dynamic array recursive

Tags: php, arrays

For example I create 2 arrays dynamically based on a path(string).

The first array looks like this:

```
array (
  2009 => 
  array (
    '08' => 
    array (
      0 => 'doc3',
      1 => 'doc4',
      2 => 'doc5',
    ),
  ),
  2010 => 
  array (
    '01' => 
    array (
      0 => 'doc6',
      1 => 'doc7',
    ),
  ),
)
```

The second array looks like this:

```
array (
  2009 => 
  array (
    '08' => 
    array (
      0 => 'doc1',
      1 => 'doc2',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Now i wanna merge this two arrays to this:

```
array (
  2009 => 
  array (
    '08' => 
    array (
      0 => 'doc1',
      1 => 'doc2',
      2 => 'doc3',
      3 => 'doc4',
      4 => 'doc5',
    ),
  ),
  2010 => 
  array (
    '01' => 
    array (
      0 => 'doc6',
      1 => 'doc7',
    ),
  ),
)
```

The biggest problem is, the array is dynamically. For example the first array can be 4 levels deep and the second can be 7 levels deep.
This comes because I create the arrays based on a path/string which I stored in my database. There should be no maximum.

To create the arrays i use this [framework](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.htm).

I create the arrays from my example with this code:

```
$data_text_1 = [];
$data_text_2 = [];
$propertyAccessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
$propertyAccessor->setValue($data_text_1, '[2009][08]', ['doc1', 'doc2']);
$propertyAccessor->setValue($data_text_2, '[2009][08]', ['doc3', 'doc4', 'doc5']);
$propertyAccessor->setValue($data_text_2, '[2010][01]', ['doc6', 'doc7']);
```

Does anyone can help me?

EDIT:

I already tried array_merge_recursive. After the use of array_merge_recursive my array looks like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    '08' => 
    array (
      0 => 'doc1',
      1 => 'doc2',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    '08' => 
    array (
      0 => 'doc3',
      1 => 'doc4',
      2 => 'doc5',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    '01' => 
    array (
      0 => 'doc6',
      1 => 'doc7',
    ),
  ),
)
```

EDIT 2 @misorude

This are the arrays to merge:

```
array (
  2009 => 
  array (
    '08' => 
    array (
      0 => 'doc1',
      1 => 'doc2',
    ),
  ),
)


array (
  2009 => 
  array (
    '08' => 
    array (
      'temp' => 
      array (
        0 => 'doc3',
        1 => 'doc4',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)


array (
  2009 => 
  array (
    '08' => 
    array (
      0 => 'doc5',
      1 => 'doc6',
      2 => 'doc7',
    ),
  ),
  2010 => 
  array (
    '01' => 
    array (
      0 => 'doc8',
      1 => 'doc9',
    ),
  ),
)
```

And this are the expected merge:

```
array (
  2009 => 
  array (
    '08' => 
    array (
      0 => 'doc1',
      1 => 'doc2',
      2 => 'doc5',
      3 => 'doc6',
      4 => 'doc7',
      'temp' => 
      array (
        0 => 'doc3',
        1 => 'doc4',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  2010 => 
  array (
    '01' => 
    array (
      0 => 'doc8',
      1 => 'doc9',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: [array_merge_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge-recursive.php) can help you.

Comment: @marv255 That isn't giving what the OP expects. Also, please attach only `en` links.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does not work properly with array_merge_recursive

Comment: @egolive Can you guarantee that both arrays will have the same keys, even deeply?

Comment: _“For example the first array can be 4 levels deep and the second can be 7 levels deep.”_ - can you show an example for that kind of situation then, please? Not necessarily that many levels - but what the actual result is supposed to look like in that case then. What if [2009][08][0] was `doc3` in the first array, but in the second one [2009][08][0] was itself an array again - what would the “merge” of that look like then?

Comment: @vivek_23 no the keys can be different

Comment: If `array_merge_recursive` can't help, merge them by hand, is there any difficulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the array structures you provided, below code works for me. We go through each of the arrays and check:

- If key is not set, set it in the `$result`(note the `&` used to edit the same copy of $result).
- If key is set, and value is not an array, add it to `$result`.
- If value is an array, then recursively call the `mergeRecursive()` function again with `$result[$key]` and `$value` as the parameters.

**Code:**

```
<?php


$arr1 = array (
  2009 => 
  array (
    '08' => 
    array (
      0 => 'doc1',
      1 => 'doc2',
    ),
  ),
);


$arr2 = array (
  2009 => 
  array (
    '08' => 
    array (
      'temp' => 
      array (
       'doc3',
       'doc4',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);


$arr3 = array (
  2009 => 
  array (
    '08' => 
    array (
      'doc5',
      'doc6',
      'doc7',
    ),
  ),
  2010 => 
  array (
    '01' => 
    array (
     'doc8',
      'doc9',
    ),
  ),
);

$merge_arrays = [$arr2,$arr3];

$result = $arr1;

foreach($merge_arrays as $array){
    mergeRecursive($result,$array);
}

function mergeRecursive(&$result,$arr){
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        if(!isset($result[$key])){
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }else if(is_array($value)){
            mergeRecursive($result[$key],$value);
        }else{
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }
}


print_r($result);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/o4NLW

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @egolive Glad to help :)